# getting Element is not clickable at point (355, 160) exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

My script is failing because of the following exception.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not
>   clickable at point (355, 160)

While loading the page if the element appears in the background, selenium tries to click and fails. I have used webdriverwait. Out of 10 times it fails around 3 times minimum.

How can I avoid/handle this without using Thread.sleep();

[image]

Comment: u can wait untill invisibility of element (please wait loading...)

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this.

Comment: let me know what happens

Comment: Thanks for that. As of now it's working. I have to observe for a while.

Comment: if that worked i will convert it to answer but u already accept an answer which is like my comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wait until invisibility of element using `invisibilityOfElementLocated` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath('xpath of please wait loading...')));
```

After this you could perform `click` on target `element`

Hope it will work..:)

Comment: Yes it did. I will for a while :)

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit wait

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myElement")));
// or (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(
    //    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("myElement")));
myElement .click();
```

Comment: @PrakashP try adding Thread.sleep(5000); before the Webelement and then go for explicit wait. Some times that worked for me.