# Selenium Webdriver - Wait until a scroll bar appears on the screen

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have started automating using selenium webdriver. My application is having a vertical scroll bar and no action can be performed in the page until that vertical scroll bar is loaded. I want my selenium commands to wait until that scroll bar is loaded Any suggestions..

Comment: Can you specify any text or element be present at the bottom of the page after scroll bar finish loading.

Comment: And could you add some code to show what you tried?

Comment: May be it will help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745651/getting-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-355-160-exception/37745882#37745882

Comment: It is hard to tell which element is loaded after a scroll bar, since once scroll bar is loaded and i scroll down the page is loaded by the time.

Answer (score 2):

Some more information would be appreciated. You can try using JavascriptExecutor though

```
    String script = "return document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;";
    JavascriptExecutor scrollBar = (JavascriptExecutior) driver;
    Boolean test = (Boolean) (scrollBar.executeScript(script));
    // You can use "test" as and when required to check if the scroll bar is loaded.
```